# 'No job functions found' .Net Azure Function after migration from Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus to Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus

Tags: c#, azure-functions, .net-4.8

I am migrating some legacy .Net code from an App Service into an Azure Function triggered by a Service Bus topic.  This will run under .Net Framework 4.8 as an Azure function V1.  I am running into the error "No job functions found.  Try making your job classes and methods public" etc.

To test this, I created a brand new Azure function using the Visual Studio 2022 template, and it does not have this warning.  However, looking at the NuGet packages, I can see that the template installs Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus, which is deprecated.

[image: NuGet packages installed by the template]

I removed that package and installed the new Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus package that is recommended.

[image: Updated packages]

The only change to the code that I had to make was to remove the AccessRights attribute, since that's not supported any more.

Now, when I run the Azure Function, I get the "No job functions found" warning.

[image: No job functions found]

The warning suggests that I am supposed to call config.UseServiceBus() somewhere.  I've seen from some questions on this where people do this in Program.cs in the Main function.  However, this is a DLL library project, so there is no Program.cs or startup code.

I've looked for a Migration Guide and searched for similar problems, but everything I've found is for .Net 5, not Framework 4.8.

What is the correct way to initialize a .Net48 Azure Function built as a DLL?  Should I convert this project to a Console Program instead, and initialize in Main()?

Edit:
This is the template-generated function that works before updating the library:

```c#
    using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
    using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
    using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;
    
    namespace AFTest
    {
        public static class Function1
        {
            [FunctionName("Function1")]
            public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("testtopic", "testsubscription", AccessRights.Listen, Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")]string mySbMsg, TraceWriter log)
            {
                log.Info($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's the slightly modified code (removing the Access attribute) that doesn't work:

```c#
    using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
    using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
    
    namespace AFTest
    {
        public static class Function1
        {
            [FunctionName("Function1")]
            public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("testtopic", "testsubscription", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")]string mySbMsg, TraceWriter log)
            {
                log.Info($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does your function method look like? Show us some code.

Comment: I edited the post to include the code, but it's really just the Visual Studio-generated template code.

Comment: Are you running inside VS?  Looks like you need Admin.  Did you right click VS shortcut and Select Run As Admin?

Comment: Yes, I am running inside VS.  Based on your comment, I tried running VS as an admin, but it didn't have any effect.  Also, I should add that I get this same error in the Kudu logs when I deploy it to Azure.

Comment: I still hope someone might know the answer to this, but for now I just decided to convert to .Net 6.  That trigger works fine.  Converting the codebase to .Net 6 seems like a better use of time than trying to get .Net Framework 4.8 working.